# VSCode Pylance temporary reports missing Modules

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flask, pylance

I have the following lines on a `hello.py` file:

```
from typing import Any
from flask import Flask
```

This is on a brand new virtual environment that I just created.
`Pylance` is **temporarily** reporting `flask` as a missing module. I emphasise **temporarily** because I know if I don't do anything, `pylance` will get there eventually.

My question however is: **can I force `pylance` on VSCode to acknowledge that `flask` is in fact on my virtual environment?**

There are a LOT of articles on stack**overflow** about this matter, but I couldn't find an answer to my question (feel free to direct me to the right place).

Before helping me, please take into consideration that I have run through this checklist already:

- I do have a LocalPython virtual environment.
- It is activated on VSCode (I can see `3.12.1 ('LocalPython': venv)` at the bottom right).
- The code is actually running properly.
- When I open a New Terminal, the `LocalPython` virtual environment is activated.
- In the terminal, if I run `python` and then I run `import flask` on the `python` prompt, it does import the `flask` module.
- I can see the `flask` directory on `LocalPython/lib/flask`.
- I have issued the command `Python: Clear Cache and Reload Window`.
- I have restarted VSCode.
- I have restarted my Mac.
- I have reselected the local interpreter to be LocalPython on VScode.
- *Sometime in the future* this shall *automagically* be fixed by itself (been there, done that, got the t-shirt!), but I would really like to find out how can I fix it on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. You could add the following codes to your `settings.json` to let Pylance know you have installed the package:

```
  "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "PATH/TO/YOUR/PACKAGE"
  ],
```